# Installing Percona 5.6 on Google Compute Engine (Debian)

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, percona

I've been trying to install percona server on a fresh Google Compute Engine instance.

I haven't installed MySQL server previously. I followed [these instructions](http://www.unixmen.com/install-percona-server-5-6-phpmyadmin-debian-7-wheezy/), and when I run:

```
apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6 percona-server-client-5.6
```

I get the following output:

```
Setting up percona-server-common-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
Setting up percona-server-client-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
Setting up percona-server-server-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL (Percona Server): mysqld.
2014-01-22 04:54:28 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.     Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.15-    rel63.0 started; log sequence number 1625987
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] RSA private key file not found:     /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] Binlog end
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-01-22 04:54:30 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625997


 * Percona Server is distributed with several useful UDF (User Defined Function) from Percona Toolkit.
 * Run the following commands to create these functions:

    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv1a_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv1a_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION murmur_hash RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libmurmur_udf.so'"

 * See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/udf_percona_toolkit.html for more details


[FAIL] Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's in the error.log?

Comment: newbie here,
are you talking about /var/log/mysql.log this is empty
or /var/log/mysql this shows it has 4096b but when i 'nano mysql' it i see nothing.

Comment: Is there a *.err file? The usual MySQL .err or .log file. It can be in the datadir, /var/log, depends where you configure it to be.

Comment: yes, mysql.err its empty. 0 bytes.

Comment: @HongTat i found a "instance-name".err in /var/lib/mysql/ 

http://tinypic.com/r/6yz0v6/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Percona Server 5.6 requires more RAM than the 0.60 GB available in the Google Compute Engine 'f1-micro' machine type. Use a larger [machine type](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) when creating your instance.